# How do I determine which WooCommerce variant of a product was bought using the product

Tags: php, woocommerce

During the woocommerce_payment_complete hook I receive the order and from that I extract the products using get_items(). From here when I loop over the items and use get_sku() to get the SKU but that returns the SKU of the main product instead of the SKU of the variant that was purchased.

I've been Googling this issue this entire day and I got loads and loads of posts telling me how to do all manner of stuff with the variant once you have the variant id... but for the life of me I can't figure out how to GET the variant id!

Simply put:
I have one product (a hat) on my site and that product has 3 variants (baseball, trilby, stetson) each with a custom SKU with Item_hat_stetson set as the default. All I want to know is "Which one of the three hats did the person choose to buy?" and yet all I can determine is:

1. Yes, he bought a hat: SKU Item_hat
2. Hats come in the varieties of baseball, trilby and stetson

How can I determine which variation the person selected?

Simple, right? ...yet for the life of me I just can't figure that out. :( Please help...

Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to get the variation_id? From the product page or cart page?

Comment: I am trying to get it when the **woocommerce_payment_complete** hook fires. As such, neither of those pages. Basically, when PayPal has done processing the order and says "Right, the transaction was complete" then I want to check which variant was purchased and then set a bunch of values in custom tables at that time. This is the problem I ran into yesterday also. Ppl have lots of answers for when the global $product or $post variable is available and all setup but I'm not ON any of those pages that will have $post or $product set. I need to get the WC_Order object myself & take it from there

Comment: So in short... The hook fires and gives me the order ID. I get the order and ....then what? I know I need to loop over the get_contents() (even though there will be only 1) and that way I get the item that was ordered. This far I get but no further. Once I have the order and selected the item from the order, how do I extract the variant value for that item? That is the part where I am stuck at... I'm sure there is a super simple WC fucnction like $theproduct->get_variant_id() but for the life of me I can't find that function / property :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your woocommerce payment complete hook.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

// Loop though order "line items"
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ){
    $product_id = $item_product->get_product_id(); //Get the product ID
    $quantity = $item_product->get_quantity(); //Get the product QTY
    $product_name = $item_product->get_name(); //Get the product NAME

     // Get an instance of the WC_Product object (can be a product variation  too)
    $product = $item_product->get_product();

     // Get the product description (works for product variation)
    $description = $product->get_description();

    // Only for product variation
    if($product->is_type('variation')){
         // Get the variation attributes
        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        // Loop through each selected attributes
        foreach($variation_attributes as $attribute_taxonomy => $term_slug){
            $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute_taxonomy );
            // The name of the attribute
            $attribute_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            // The term name (or value) for this attribute
            $attribute_value = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that post a few hours ago also. I copy pasted that code just as is and then after setting $attribute_value I used $wpdb->replace to add the name and value to my custom table to see what was returned. Short answer: Nothing :( Thing is, though, this is a variable subscription, not just a variation so I figured that "if" was preventing this from working but since I know it is the only product and it is a variation I removed the "if" and tried it again. Still nothing. You have no idea how frustrated I am at this point! :(

Comment: ahh, OK man. Well without seeing the underlying code I don't really know how else to help you :/

Could run your code and use echo "<pre>"; print_r($order); die('dead');
Update your answer with the output and I can see how hings are working.

Comment: I'll post some code in a second as it seems I actually made some progress to the point where I found the purchased item in the post table. Also, inside the woocommerce_orde_itemmeta table I can see the _product_id and _variation_id keys with the values I expect them to have. They are linked to order 185 but I can't seem to find a way to link post 1814 that gives me wc_order_jPoPJkNzbTdnT in postmeta under _order_key to anything that will link me to order 185 So close and yet so far...

Comment: I am still not able to get the SKU but via a very roundabout hack I can at least identify the product now by first using get_items(), looping over it to get to the first item, then calling wcs_get_users_subscriptions() on that entry before looping across that before fetching the post meta for the item id that I can then use to fetch the KEY from woocommerce_order_items by using the value I have to search against the VALUE in that table. Once I've done that I will have a name I can split/parse to get the variation name and also the key to the other table with the actual data. This cant be right

Answer (score 0):

```
function after_purchase( $order_id )
{
    global $wpdb;   
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item)
    {
        if ($item['quantity'] <= 0) continue;

        $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
        if (!$product) continue;

        $item_data = $item->get_data();

        if (function_exists('wcs_get_users_subscriptions'))
        {
            $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions();
            foreach($subscriptions as $subscription)
            {
                if ($subscription->has_product($product->id))
                {
                    //can't use this. Don't know how
                    $order_key = get_post_meta($subscription->get_id(),'_order_key',true);

                    $item_post = $subscription->get_id();
                    $query = "SELECT order_item_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items "
                            ."WHERE order_id = '$item_post'";
                    $order_number = $wpdb->get_var($query);
                    $query2 = "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta "
                            . "WHERE order_item_id = '$order_number' AND meta_key ='edition'";
                    $variation_identifier = $wpdb->get_var($query2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets me the data I want but this has GOT to be the wrong way of doing this.....

In this code snippet I fetch the custom property I created for the product and I am happy enough with that as a way to identify the products from one another but what I SHOULD have done (apparently) was to search against the meta_key '_variation_id' instead of 'edition' to obtain the post table ID that will give me the product that I can then load using WC_Product t finally get the SKU from that... That is wayyy too many calls to make to get something as simple as an SKU...

Can someone please show me the right way?

Thanks